# Young tableaux in commutative diagram with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, ytableau

Why are blank boxes inserted in the Young tableaux that are part of a tikz-cd environment? Is there a way to fix this while still using the Young tableaux and the tikz-cd?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\begin{tikzcd}
    \begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 3
    \end{ytableau}
    \arrow[color=black, swap]{d}{f}
    \\
    \begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 4
    \end{ytableau}
\end{tikzcd}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Try saving the `ytableau` to boxes and then using the boxes inside `tikzcd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! There are two issues:

1. the ampersands `&` get used both by the matrix and the Young tableau.
2. this approach <s>nests `tikzpictures`</s> uses pgf keys (statement corrected, big thanks to @cfr), so it might be conceivable that the outer keys affect the inner ones (yet glancing through `ytableau.sty` this appears to be unlikely).

The safest way is to, as suggested by @cfr, store the Young tableaux in `\savebox`es and use them. However, it turns out that in your case (and in probably almost all cases) it is already sufficient to address the first issue by using an `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    \begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 3
    \end{ytableau}
    \arrow[color=black, swap]{d}{f}
    \\
    \begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 4
    \end{ytableau}
\end{tikzcd}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: The safer option (as suggested by @cfr), which yields the same output.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}
\newsavebox\youngA
\newsavebox\youngB
\begin{document}
\savebox\youngA{\begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 3
    \end{ytableau}}%
\savebox\youngB{\begin{ytableau}
    1 & 2 \\ 4
    \end{ytableau}}%    
$\displaystyle
\begin{tikzcd}
    \usebox\youngA
    \arrow[color=black, swap]{d}{f}
    \\
    \usebox\youngB
\end{tikzcd}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution! Thank you! I tried a few different things but grew frustrated with my failures... :}

Comment: I am curious: How would one save each tableaux in a savebox?

Comment: @Pete You are welcome! I added it to the answer. Please note that you could also use another package for drawing the young tableaux, e.g. `young` or `youngtab`, both of which do not rely on Ti*k*Z. BTW, I think that the first option should be rather safe, given that `ytableau` uses mainly its "own" pgf keys.

Comment: @cfr Well, it uses pgf keys, so in principle the symptoms might be the same, but you are right: "nesting `tikzpicture`s" is not entirely correct.